# append modal: how to fadeIn the background (parent) but not the modal content (child)

Tags: css, background, modal-dialog, append

I'm using a WP plugin which append a modal login form. I'm looking for a way to only fadeIn the background color from transparent to rgba(0,0,0.9), but I want the modal content appears directly, without fade effect. I've tried this:

```
transition: background-color 2s ease;
```

but it doesn't work. Here is how the code looks like:

**HTML**

```
<button>click</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.modal {   
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    transition: background-color 2s ease;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**JS**

```
$("button").click(function() {
  $("body").append(
  "<div class='modal'>" +
    "<div class='modal-content'>HELLO WORLD!</div>" +
  "</div>");
});
```

The full code [**HERE**](https://codepen.io/dragoeco/pen/qjqjgy)

I spent hours searching a working solution but without success :/ Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution (seems obvious now :p ) :

```
$("button").click(function() {
 $(".modal").fadeIn().css("background-color","rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9)");
});
```